# What is Time Complexity for Arrays.stream() O(n) or O(n log n)?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, time-complexity

Stream API documentation says:

> certain stream sources (such as `List` or **arrays**) are **intrinsically
> ordered**, whereas others (such as `HashSet`) are not.

What would be the time complexity of `Arrays.stream()` method?

**O(n log n)**, as it returns sorted array, or **O(n)**, as we expect from `stream()`s methods ?

Comment: Why do you think it sorts an array?

Comment: Reference [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) states that. Additionally, the output to below code line is sorting the input provided : `Set<Integer> seen = Arrays.stream(new int[] {2, 3 ,8,7,1,0}).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: I think you're confusing encounter order and sorted. -- and that gives you a set, not an array, using its own internal ordering of values unrelated to the original arrays.

Comment: okay, what would be the time complexity for this line of code, as the elements in the set object (output) is in ascending order : 
`Set<Integer> seen = Arrays.stream(new int[] {2, 3 ,8,7,1,0}).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: The current implementation of `Collectors.toSet()` uses a `HashSet` with O(1) insertion, so it takes O(N) time to insert every element of an array N elements long.

Answer (score 4):

> **O(n)** or **O(nlogn)** ?

Neither of these.

***Firstly***, it seems like you're confusing a stream which elements are sorted with an ordered stream, i.e. a stream which has a particular *encounter order* of elements.

Whether a stream is ordered or not depends on the stream source and intermediate operations in it.

A stream created over an array, or ordered collection like a `List`, or a `Queue` is ordered respectively to order elements in it, but it does **not** imply that such stream is sorted.

We can make a stream unordered by applying `unordered()` operation on in it. This operation alone will not change the stream data, but it will have an impact on the execution of *stateful intermediate* operations like `takeWhile()` that require buffering, and *terminal* operation like `reduce()`, `collect()` that give a guarantee to respect the initial encounter order. As a result, a parallel unordered stream might have better performance because of loosening this constraint.

Here is a quote from the [*API documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering):

> Ordering
>
> Streams may or may not have a defined *encounter order*. Whether or
> not a stream has an encounter order **depends on the source** and the
> **intermediate operations**. Certain stream sources (such as `List` or **arrays**) are
> **intrinsically ordered**, whereas others (such as `HashSet`)
> are not. Some intermediate operations, such as `sorted()`, may impose an
> encounter order on an otherwise unordered stream, and others may
> render an ordered stream unordered, such as `BaseStream.unordered()`.
> Further, some terminal operations may ignore encounter order, such as
> `forEach()`.
>
> If a stream is ordered, most operations are constrained to operate on
> the elements in their encounter order; if the source of a stream is a
> List containing `[1, 2, 3]`, then the result of executing `map(x -> x*2)`
> must be `[2, 4, 6]`. However, if the source has no defined encounter
> order, then any permutation of the values `[2, 4, 6]` would be a valid
> result.
>
> For sequential streams, the presence or absence of an encounter order
> does not affect performance, only determinism. If a stream is ordered,
> repeated execution of identical stream pipelines on an identical
> source will produce an identical result; if it is not ordered,
> repeated execution might produce different results.
>
> For parallel streams, relaxing the ordering constraint can sometimes
> enable more efficient execution. Certain aggregate operations, such as
> filtering duplicates (`distinct()`) or grouped reductions
> (`Collectors.groupingBy()`) can be implemented more efficiently if
> ordering of elements is not relevant. Similarly, operations that are
> intrinsically tied to encounter order, such as `limit()`, may require
> buffering to ensure proper ordering, undermining the benefit of
> parallelism. In cases where the stream has an encounter order, but the
> user does not particularly care about that encounter order, explicitly
> de-ordering the stream with `unordered()` may improve parallel
> performance for some stateful or terminal operations. However, most
> stream pipelines, such as the "sum of weight of blocks" example above,
> still parallelize efficiently even under ordering constraints.

***Secondly***, because you're assuming that creating a stream over an array will cost at list **O(n)** you might have a misconception regarding the nature of streams.

In essence, stream is a **mean of iteration**, it is **not** a container of data like Collection.

Creation of a stream doesn't require dumping all the data from the source into memory, we're only creating an internal iterator over the source of data, and this action has a time complexity of **O(1)**.

Streams are **lazy** and every action in the stream pipeline occur only when it's needed, and elements from the source are processed one by one.

For instance, let's assume we have an integer array containing `1,000,000` elements, and we want to get the first `10` elements from it as hexadecimal strings:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(sourceArray)
    .mapToObj(Integer::toHexString)
    .limit(10)
    .toList();
```

On execution, only the first `10` elements would be retrieved  from the source array, and then the stream would immediately terminate, producing the result.

The overall time complexity of such a stream would be **O(1)** because we care only about a fixed number of elements at the very beginning, and don't need all the data that the source contains.

Comment: Nitpick: since the Big O notation expresses the worst case, as long as we can’t predict the distribution of even numbers over the source array, the operation still is O(n). Things would be different if you omit the filter or when discussing average and best cases…

Comment: @Holger Sure, that indisputable - executing the stream would cost `O(n)`. But creation of a stream has a cost `O(1)`, that all that I intended to convey. I didn't mean that sample-code will run in `O(1)`, it's still `O(n)`. I just wanted to illustrate that a stream isn't a container of data, like in the example it can process `10` elements out of `1M` and we are done. Or I've missed your point?

Comment: The interesting point about `Arrays.stream(sourceArray)` being O(1) is that you can chain operations to be less than O(n) in total, like `Arrays.stream(sourceArray).mapToObj(Integer::toHexString) .limit(10).toList()`. With `filter`, you still have O(n) which does not necessarily demonstrate the point for someone only focusing on Big O time complexity like the OP.

Comment: @Holger Now I see, you're right, this example more illustrative. Incorporated it into the answer.